# LD_LIBRARY_PATH not being used when set in .zshrc

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, zsh

In my `.zshrc` file I have the following line:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='~/.local/lib'
```

I can confirm that the variable has been set correctly by echoing the variable from the command line:

```
> echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
~/.local/lib
```

I have a program that requires a library, `foo.so.1`, found in this local lib directory. Running directly from the command line fails:

```
> bar -v 123
bar: error when loading shared libraries: foo.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, if I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH manually before running the command everything works fine:

```
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/.local/lib bar -v 123
Success!
```

My question is: why does setting the variable immediately before running the command work, while setting it in `.zshrc` fails?

Comment: Have you tried using expanded version of `~`. It could be using it inlide causes ~ to be expanded to "/home/user" (or whatever it points to) while reading this value from environment does not do expansion.

Comment: It turns out the problem *was* that ``~`` wasn't getting expanded, but for a different reason: when I retyped the ``.zshrc`` line into the question, I ommitted the surrounding single-quotes (see edited question). The single-quotes prevented the tile from being expanded; removing them makes everything work fine.

Comment: @rpy If you add that as an answer, I'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure your env variable gets assigned the path with "~" being expanded to your home directory as such expansion will not take place when the variable is being read.

Your (revised) code uses single quotes. Those will prevent expansion from taking place.